# activemq jmx mbeans not visible from remote host

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I got `activemq` running on remote server. When I connect to it from my dev machine using `JMX` (for example with `jconsole`), I see only some of beans (broker `MBean`, but not `MBeans` of queues, topics, connections etc.), where as from with in server they are all visible.

How it could be that some beans not visible from other machines?

Comment: you should post your answer and mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that **multiple instances** of broker were running, and MBeanServer was not started properly. Killed all broker process, and clean start did the job